# Conversion char > hex

Tags: c++, hex, character

I'm trying to read a file from disk, and output its hex rappresentation.

The code I used is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
        ifstream file ("mestxt", ios::binary);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
                char* buffer;
                buffer= new char[0];
                cout<< "File open"<<endl;
                int count=0;
                while (file.good())
                {
                        file.read(buffer, 1);
                        cout<<hex<<int(*buffer)<<" ";
                        count++;
                        if (count%16==0) cout<<endl;
                }
                file.close();
        }
}
```

It works, but it just... horrifies me, I can't help but think that there MUST exist some functions that do what I've done, just better.

Input:

> bn0y5328w9gprjvn87350pryjgfpxl

Output:

> File open
>
> 62 6e 30 79 35 33 32 38 77 39 67 70 72 6a 76 6e
>
> 38 37 33 35 30 70 72 79 6a 67 66 70 78 6c 6c

Comment: `buffer= new char[0];` looks **very-very wrong.**

Comment: Aside from allocating a zero sized buffer [that probably doesn't need to be allocated at all, since all you need is one char], I don't see what you are moaning about. Sure, there are some stylistic/reliability changes [.e.g. not printing the last character twice when you read one past the end], but this is pretty much how I would do this.

Comment: Instead of `char* buffer = new char[0]` (which is wrong) use `char buffer;`, `file.read(&buffer, 1);` and `cout << hex << int(buffer) << " ";` No need to allocate memory on the heap for one character.

Comment: What I mean is, I'm 75% sure that I'm misusing the <ios> libraries, I thought that there could be some methods I could use, but I tried to read the documentations withouth success.

Comment: Your program works, so the question should be migrated to the codereview site. I flagged for moderator's attention, if moderators agree, the migration should happen soon.

Comment: (thanks, didn't know of a codereview site)

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple way of doing this. Just let STL take care of setting up a loop. If you only care about outputting the hex codes, here is the simplest version:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream is("content", ios::binary);
    cout << hex;
    copy(
       istream_iterator<char>(is), 
       istream_iterator<char>(), 
       ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")
       );
}
```

If you also want to count the number of characters and do the formatting, you should change it into the following:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cnt = 0; // Will hold the number of characters
    ifstream is("content", ios::binary);
    cout << hex;
    transform(
        istream_iterator<char>(is),
        istream_iterator<char>(),
        ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "), [&cnt] (char c) -> int {
            if (cnt % 16 == 0) cout << endl;
            cnt++; 
            return c; 
            }
        );
}
```

The above is using a lambda function, so it requires C++11. However, you can easily achieve the same with a custom-defined functor in C++98.

Comment: This would be the use of already existing libraries I've been searching for. I'd still have the problem of the use of <ios> libraries to get the correct number of character from the input file though, and I'd still have problems here.

Comment: +1 Very nice use of the Standard Library to the max!

Comment: @user1722791: You can easily change the above to count the number of characters. Let me do that.

Comment: @user1722791: There you go.

Comment: @user1722791: You're welcome, hope it helped :-)

Comment: Uhm. It fails the compilation, something about the lambda function in line 21 (one of the errors is:

error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(std::istream_iterator<char>, std::istream_iterator<char>, std::ostream_iterator<int>, main()::<lambda(char)>)’   )


I'm using the latest g++, so g++11 should be already enabled; still can't figure out the errors.

Comment: @user1722791: It works here. Did you include all the necessary headers from the example?

Comment: Yep. So I suppose it's a compatiblity problem, I'll search if I'm missing the '11 packages

Comment: @user1722791: Are you using the `-std=c++11` compilation option? It also seems to compile [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3MMZHS$13)

Comment: @AndyProwl Your second example would actually be shorter & cleaner as a traditional loop. You can pretty much write most loops with `copy` or `transform` or `generate`, etc. It doesn't always result in cleaner code.

Comment: That was the problem. I had also to move the cnt++ after just before the return c, or else it would have cout'ed after the 15th byte

Comment: @Dave: Not always maybe, but most of the time it is faster, less error-prone, more flexible, sometimes shorter, and *standard*. And this is one of the cases I believe (apart from the length, which is roughly the  same). But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @user1722791: Good catch, I fixed that in my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from an easy to fix undefined behavior (allocation of `char[0]` instead of `char[1]`, followed by writing into `buffer[0]` - one byte past the allocated space), your program is OK. You can use a scalar in place of a single-element array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file ("mestxt", ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        char buffer;
        cout<< "File open"<<endl;
        int count=0;
        while (file.good())
        {
            file.read(&buffer, 1);
            cout<<hex<<int(buffer)<<" ";
            if ((++count)%16==0) cout<<endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

You can make your program a lot more efficient by reading more than one character at a time, but on inputs of small size it does not matter at all.

Comment: I can't read a line at a time because I can't suppose that the input files has lines at all; I could read 16 bytes instead of 1, but I'd have problems of repetitions if !file.good()

Comment: @user1722791 You're right, this is binary. Still you can provide larger buffers, and get multiple characters in a single call to `file.read`. There would be a nested loop, though.

Comment: If you move "file.read()" into the while [removing `file.good()`], you won't get the repeated last char (6c twice in the output listed above, where there is only one 'l' in the file itself).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I thought so; I could empty the buffer before each file.read and cout to avoid the repetition problem, but I don't think i can trust the EOF flag, since it would be already set on after reading the last 16 bytes.

Comment: @Mats: Done. Does this makes me sure that file.good() is always true?

Comment: You don't want to use file.eof() or file.good() for loop control, as you will (nearly) always loop one more loop than you meant to, because the marker of "not good" or "end of file" only happens when you have read "past" the end of the file. Of course, if you couldn't open the file, file.good() is false, but you already test "file.is_open()", so that shouldn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your file is going to be small enough to fit in memory it is *much* faster to read the entire file into a buffer and then parse it:

```
std::ifstream file("mestxt", std::ios_base::binary);
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
std::vector<char> buffer(file.tellg()); 
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
file.read(&buffer.front(), buffer.size());

std::cout << std::hex;
std::copy(buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: While it's true for my aim (romhacking, basically), I can't be always sure of that.

Comment: @user1722791 Even still, you should loop over large chunks (of a size you  know will fit in memory) instead of reading a character at a time. You'll get hit for file IO a character at a time in the real world :)